# Where to place a robots.txt file in a Python 2.7/Bottle application on OpenShift?

Tags: python-2.7, openshift, robots.txt, bottle

**Environment**

- Python 2.7
- OpenShift

Application Structure:

```
.git
.openshift
data
libs
wsgi
 - static
 - views
 - application
 - my_bottle_app.py
README.md
setup.py
setup.pyc
setup.pyo
```

**Desired Behaviour**

I'm wanting to create `robots.txt` rules for files in the location:

```
wsgi/static/file_1.txt
wsgi/static/file_2.txt
```

For example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /file_1.txt
Disallow: /file_2.txt
```

**Question**

Should the `robots.txt` file be placed in either

- `wsgi`
- `wsgi/static`
- or the 'root' of the application structure?

**Edit:**

To clarify, the app is a [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) application so there are a number of routes that serve different content.

Additionally, all pages are served via `https` with a custom function:

```
def redirect_http_to_https(callback):
    '''Bottle plugin that redirects all http requests to https'''

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    scheme = request.urlparts[0]
    if scheme == 'http':
        # request is http; redirect to https
        redirect(request.url.replace('http', 'https', 1))
    else:
        # request is already https; okay to proceed
        return callback(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

install(redirect_http_to_https)
```

So I'm trying to understand where `robots.txt` should be placed so that it is served correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

This was the specific solution that seems to have worked informed by user unor's answer.

Add the Bottle route in Python app:

```
@route('/robots.txt')
def serve_robots():
    return static_file('robots.txt', root='app-root/repo/wsgi/static/')
```

And then add `robots.txt` to `wsgi/static/`.

The `robots.txt` file is then accessible at.

```
https://app-username.rhcloud.com/robots.tx
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn’t matter where you place the robots.txt file in your backend.
It only matters where the robots.txt is accessible from the Web.

For each *host*, the file must be available at `/robots.txt`. So it must always be in the host’s root, never in a sub-folder.

**Examples:**

When a bot wants to crawl `http://example.com/wsgi/static/file_1.txt`, it should look for a robots.txt on `http://example.com/robots.txt`.

If it is `https://example.com/wsgi/static/file_1.txt` (https instead of http), the location must be `https://example.com/robots.txt`.
If it is `http://www.example.com/wsgi/static/file_1.txt` (with subdomain), the location must be `http://www.example.com/robots.txt`